# How to properly register a single app-wide window listener with access to store in Nuxt JS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I've been trying to figure out how to attach a `window resize` listener in NuxtJS app to determine whether screen width suggests mobile or pc screen.

I use several layouts, so I'd like to avoid defining the listener in each of them. Therefore, I need to create is elsewhere. So far I've tried

1) Create a mixin

```
const mixin {
  mounted() { ...code to determine mobile devices }
}

export default {
   install(Vue) {
     Vue.mixin(mixin);
   },
};
```

I exported and then installed the mixin using `Vue.use(handleResize)`. I registered this plugin in `nuxt.config.js`. However, this made the mixin to fire (not surprisingly) in each of the component I have, not just once in total.

2) Used delayed mixin

As suggested by [IlyaSemenov](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1593#issuecomment-384554130%22Ilya%20Semenov%22) , I used his method to register the listener.

```
import extend from '@/utils/extend-vue-app';
import isMobile from '@/utils/isMobile';
import throttle from 'lodash.throttle'

function handleResizeUtil(app) {
  const mobile = isMobile();
  if (mobile !== app.store.state.utils.isMobile) {
    app.store.commit('utils/TOGGLE_IS_MOBILE', mobile);
  }
}

const handleWindowResize = throttle(function(app) {
  handleResizeUtil(app);
}, 250);

export default async function ({ app }) {
    extend(app, {
        mounted () {
         handleWindowResize(app);
         window.addEventListener('resize', () => handleWindowResize(app));
        },
    })
}
```

This works well so far. My problem is though, that this is quite a lot of code to create an application-wide event listener.

So my question is if anybody knows of a way how to register a window listener only once and have an access to vuex store? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you should be able to create a client side only plugin to handle that:

**plugins/resize.js**

```
export default ({ store }, inject) => {
    store.dispatch('WINDOW_SIZE_CHANGED')
    window.onresize = () => {
        store.dispatch('WINDOW_SIZE_CHANGED')
    }
}
```

You just need to register it in `nuxt.config.js`, and mark it as `ssr: false` to not trigger the plugin on the server side:

**nuxt.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/resize', ssr: false }
  ]
}
```

I did not try it yet, but I think that this is the best way to go.

Comment: I just tested and it works like a charm, you can use it ;)

Comment: I tried it similarly at first and couldn't access store. No idea why, because your code indeed works like a charm. I'll use your pattern, much appreciated.